# Translate Magento String "Search Results for"

Tags: search

On my Magento install Im using Portuguese language, all strings are translated OK, except on search page results the page title shows english text

Search Results for...

On app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml I have:

```
<h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper
```

('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?>

I know that that's the one line that produces the page title since if I add a character to the section

```
$this->__("Search results for '%s'"
```

The website shows that change...

On Mage_Catalogsearch.csv I have:

```
"Search results for '%s'","Resultados da pesquisa por: '%s'"
```

But still, translation not working for this specific string.

Any idea why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely culprit is that your cache needs to be cleared.

Next most likely is the fact that these csv files are very particular about characters. If you're copy-pasting the wrong char into it, it won't work. Try copying a pre-existing line from an existing translation csv and edit the content inside of the quotation marks.

*Sidenote:* typically this file is called `Mage_CatalogSearch.csv` - I did however attempt adding this string to an en_US locale translation and change the filename to `Mage_Catalogsearch.csv` and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Changing the name of file to Mage_CatalogSearch.csv and cleaning cache worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can translate this part from your theme, folder(Theme/Vendor/i18n/en_US.csv).
Add this line:

```
"Search results for: '%1'","Translate text for Search results for: %1"
```

Be careful with space between words,please copy my text and change translation part with your text

Answer (score 0):

insert this two lines:
"Search results for '%s'","Resultados da procura para '%s'"
"Search results for: '%s'","Resultados da procura para: '%s'"

in Mage_Core.csv
and done.